Chrome Selenium show file downloaded but I can't find it or click the file in download panel
Browser act as file is downloaded, I can see the file in the panel, but I can't open folder or click on the link in the panel, nor find the file in its designated downloadpath or anywhere else. Worked fine with chrome v121.
test outputs: 20241122162434|ERROR|downloadpath:C:\dist\work\remote-eseal-fullstack-test
So I know it is executing the cdp command. But nothing in downloadpath, or anywhere else.
Same Chrome the usual way work all fine, but not via selenium. Not manual in this window either.
All active chrome settings below extracted:
elif os.environ['WEBDRIVER'].lower()=='chrome':
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
  options.add_argument('--default-shm-size=32m')
  options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")   #from v127
  ptions.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
  options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
  options.set_capability('acceptInsecureCerts', True)
  s = ChromeService(log_output="./chromedriver.log", service_args=['--append-log', '--readable-timestamp', '--log-level=DEBUG'])
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  if downloadpath:
    params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': downloadpath}
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
    log.error(f"downloadpath:{downloadpath}")

Chromedriver: 131.0.6778.69, Chrome: 131.0.6778.86, Selenium: 4.26.1, win11
In chromedriver.log I see this:
[11-22-2024 15:50:50.149][INFO]: [8910dee67519a9b5866d52afebfbf3c1] COMMAND ExecuteCDP {
   "cmd": "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
   "params": {
      "behavior": "allow",
      "downloadPath": "C:\\dist\\work\\remote-eseal-fullstack-test"
   }
}
[11-22-2024 15:50:50.149][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[11-22-2024 15:50:50.149][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Runtime.evaluate (id=11) (session_id=61E316801F90E64FADC42C44338093B5) A4E93A55626FB44C23A9F9249BA7239F {
   "expression": "1"
}
[11-22-2024 15:50:50.150][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Runtime.evaluate (id=11) (session_id=61E316801F90E64FADC42C44338093B5) A4E93A55626FB44C23A9F9249BA7239F {
   "result": {
      "description": "1",
      "type": "number",
      "value": 1
   }
}
[11-22-2024 15:50:50.150][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[11-22-2024 15:50:50.150][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Command: Page.setDownloadBehavior (id=12) (session_id=61E316801F90E64FADC42C44338093B5) A4E93A55626FB44C23A9F9249BA7239F {
   "behavior": "allow",
   "downloadPath": "C:\\dist\\work\\remote-eseal-fullstack-test"
}
:
<down to last entry mentioning the pdf>
:
[11-22-2024 15:50:55.321][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Page.windowOpen (session_id=D072486C5680E0BC8FE19F80C8467224) 9A5B198EA74FBCFC94BF48195F3EB3B8 {
   "url": "https://**********/remote-eseal-demo-web/signed/buypass-finse-2022_signed.pdf",
   "userGesture": true,
   "windowFeatures": [ "menubar", "toolbar", "status", "scrollbars", "resizable", "noopener" ],
   "windowName": "_blank"
}



Unsure what the question is here.  Can you provide more details or re-state question? You shouldn't need CDP to set a download path.  Just use pref of "download.default_directory"

Sorry, Browser act as file is downloaded but the file do not exists anywhere. worked fine with Chrome v121, but not now

This works with firefox, So I will use firefox. most likely a bug in chromedriver.
